# Ionic CSS animation does not working on android device

Tags: android, css, ionic-framework

I am trying out a very simple CSS animation using Ionic Framework and it works fine in Chrome browser but on device there is no animation. And the shape also looks different. Here's my code. Can anyone suggest what's wrong with it?

```
.container {
  text-align: center;
  padding:100px;
}
.wedge {
  animation: rotate 4s infinite linear;
  border-radius: 0 64px 64px 0;
  background: green;
  width: 32px;
  height: 64px;
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
```

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="wedge"></div>
</div>
```

All it does is rotate a wedge 360 degress. But not working on android device. Thanks.

Comment: In android mobile default browser will open that's why it is unable to show the transition effect's .If it will open the chrome browser mean's it will show the effect..Some css effect's may vary from browser to browser

Comment: please add crosswalk ,It will resolve your problem

Comment: @Anilkumar : Sorry, I don't understand your answer. The code that I pasted is from my ionic test app, which runs fine in the browser while building it but doesn't work at all on android device (as an app). Can you explain your answer?

Comment: @Muhsin: Thanks. I tried crosswalk and got quite a lot of errors while installing it on the project - so parked it for now if I can understand the root of the problem - which maybe something to do with 'transform' and transform-origin, but not sure.

Comment: In android mobile device the default browser is not chrome that's why your css snippet code will not work in android mobile devices

Comment: I am having the same issue with android. It is working fine with ios and browser any one encountered that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your animations to support default Android browser. for example replace @keyframes with

> @-webkit-keyframes

, animation with -webkit-animation , transform with -webkit-transform and so on.

It fixed mine and I hope fixes yours.